# How to make something like Liftmagic

Tags: php, jquery, image, imagemagick, gd

I got a client asking for something like below site:

http://liftmagic.com/

How do we go about this?

Can I use jQuery for image manipulation or should I use something else?

I suppose I could also use server side libraries like GD for image manipulation.

Comment: This is awfully generic for SO. Do you have any specific questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use a variety of plugins to get the same functionality.

Face Detection (jQuery Plugin): http://facedetection.jaysalvat.com
Image Rotate (jQuery Plugin): http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/
Image Crop (jQuery Plugin): http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/